# How to set dependencies when I use .NET Standard 2.0 DLL libraries with a .NET Framework console application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I can't figure out how should I set up dependencies (where to add EntityFramework nuget packages) in this scenario:

1. `Core.Persistence` project which compiles to .NET Standard 2.0 DLL library. I have Entity Framework 6, database entity classes for EF, DbContext etc. It is supposed to depend just on `EntityFrameworkCore`.
2. `Core.Domain` project which also compiles to .NET Standard 2.0 DLL library. I want to put my business object POCO classes here. This is supposed to have no dependencies.
3. `Core.Application` project, this is .NET Standard 2.0 DLL library. I have all application logic here. It depends on `Core.Persistence` because it makes database queries and `Core.Domain` because it produces bussiness objects from query results.
4. `Client.ConsoleClient` project. It makes .NET Framework 4.7.2 executable. It is supposed to depend only on `Core.Application`, **but I have a problem here**.
5. `Client.WindowsClient` project which I don't want to focus in this question.

So, this is what I have done:

[image]

The problem is, that I'm getting `System.IO.FileLoadException` when I try to call method from `Core.Application`.

It says that it cannot find `System.Interactive.Async` file (which is dependency of `EntityFrameworkCore`). After I add this file as dependency - there are other `System.IO.FileLoadException` errors.

So, temporarily I have added EF6 Core NuGet package to my `Client.ConsoleClient`, and problems with `System.IO.FileLoadException` are gone, but I feel I'm doing something wrong.

At this moment I figured out, that Visual Studio is not copying DLL files from `Core.xxx` projects outputs into `Client.ConsoleClient` project output, and that's why I'm getting errors.

---

How to fix this properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a wellknown and quite old hurt logged on GitHub at:
dependencies don't flow from new `NET Standard` project to old desktop projects through project references [link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/901)

A possible solution is to add the `NuGet` dependency to the `Full NET Framework` project, as you did.

The other suggestion to include the following to the `.csproj` project file of the `Full NET Framework project` is also working for me.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that I am using package references in the `NET Standard` projects.

*As for now, it looks like `NET Standard` projects are best to be consumed as `NuGet` packages, as these would include any dependent references as `NuGet` packages into the target project.*

---

**Core.Persistence.csproj** referencing `Entity Framework`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

**Core.Application.csproj** referencing `Core.Persistence`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Core.Persistence\Core.Persistence.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

**ConsoleClient.csproj** referencing `Core.Application`

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <!-- ... -->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    </PropertyGroup>        

    <!-- ... --->

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Core.Application\Core.Application.csproj">
            <Project>{067b3201-3f65-4654-a0fb-e8fae521bf29}</Project>
            <Name>Core.Application</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

The new SDK format `csproj` files [don't play terribly well](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/901) with the legacy format project files.

But fear not as .NET Framework console apps can use the SDK format!

Make sure you have your work committed to source control, or make a copy of the folder, and then do the following:

1. Delete `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` from `Client.ConsoleClient`. We won't be needing this any more as the contents of that file now go into the project file.
2. Delete `packages.config` - again, Nuget references will be stored in the project file - that's if you need any Nuget references after we reference `Core.Application` later.
3. Open `Client.ConsoleClient.csproj` in a text editor and change the contents to:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
4. Reload the project in Visual Studio.
5. Add a reference to `Core.Application` and add any Nuget packages you need.
6. If you had any content in `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` other than versions at 1.0.0.0, right click the project in Solution Explorer and click Package. Add the details you need and then save:

[image]

That's it, although there are 2 others things you *might* need to do depending on your circumstances:

- If there are files which should be excluded, you'll need to exclude them, as the new project format includes all relevant file types by default.
- You might have to set the language version. In my Visual Studio 2019 Preview, `latest` (latest minor version of C#) is the default so I don't need to do this.